# Adding Inline HTML Code to Wagtail Rich Text Editor

Tags: django, wagtail, rich-text-editor

I am using Wagtail CMS to build a website. I now want to embed a link with image into a paragraph. As I use the wagtail rich text editor I am wondering if there is any way to use inline html inside the rich text editor.

Greetings

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `'media'` option in feature list of Richtextfield.
`body = RichTextField(features=['h2', 'h3', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', ..., 'media'])`

Or if you have to use this embed feature many times then you can define a features list in `constants.py` file as say
`RICHTEXT_FEATURES=['h2', 'h3', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', ..., 'media']`

Then do

```
from constants import RICHTEXT_FEATURES
...

body = RichTextField(features=RICHTEXT_FEATURES)
```

in your `models.py` file.
This will enable you to embed content in the richtext panel.
Refer to the documentations [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/embeds.html) and [here](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/customisation/page_editing_interface.html) for more details.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `media` option but there is an `embed` option for things like Youtube URLs.